# Touch position of new input system of Unity is infinity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    void Start()
    {
        EnhancedTouchSupport.Enable();
        UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.onFingerDown += onFingerDown;
    }

    public void onMoveAction(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
    {
        // if (ctx.started)
        //     EmmitMoveEvent((int)ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>().x);  
    }

    void onFingerDown(Finger controllFinger)
    {
        void onFingerMove(Finger finger)
        {
            if (finger.index != controllFinger.index)
                return;
            int delta = (int)((finger.screenPosition.x - controllFinger.screenPosition.x) / 100);
            if (delta != 0)
            {
                UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.onFingerMove -= onFingerMove;
                EmmitMoveEvent(delta);
            }
        }

        void onFingerUp(Finger finger)
        {
            if (finger.index != controllFinger.index)
                return;

            UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.onFingerDown += onFingerDown;
            UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.onFingerMove -= onFingerMove;
            UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.onFingerUp -= onFingerUp;
        }

        UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.onFingerDown -= onFingerDown;
        UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.onFingerMove += onFingerMove;
        UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.onFingerUp += onFingerUp;
    }

    void EmmitMoveEvent(int direction)
    {
        EventHandler<MoveEventArgs> moveEvent = MoveEvent;
        if (moveEvent != null)
            moveEvent(this, new MoveEventArgs(direction));
    }
```

the value of screenPosition is sometimes (Infinity, - Infinity), although one call, one time the value is a regular number, the next time Infinity. I don't know what the problem is, maybe someone faced a similar situation

Comment: Why are you constantly monkeying with the delegates? Just set them in Start and leave them alone. I can't tell if that's the issue or not but it's difficult to look at to the point that I'm not thing to try to figure out what the intent is here.

Comment: @Chuck In advance, sorry for the long text, I will explain everything from the beginning. I need the first finger touched by the device to be set as the main and control and so that all subsequent touches are not learned and as soon as this finger is removed from the device, you can set a new control finger, I do not like to use flags and garbage fields in the class, so I use a closure and area of ​​visibility. I come from js and maybe my approach is not correct. But I'm just trying to implement finger control. Thanks for reading)

Comment: You could make a bool like isTouched and either cache the finger ID or ignore the action. It's not adding that much extra code and would let you avoid all the delegate hijinks. Notable possible bugs are in the onFingerMove callback. You check if finger != control Finger and return if they're not equal, but then if they are equal you take the difference between the two to calculate the delta. Shouldn't that always be zero? But then if (somehow) it isn't zero you unsubscribe the callback so you can't make any subsequent moves until you lift and touch again, right?

Comment: I guess to your question specifically, there's nothing in your code that looks like it's dividing by zero, so I don't think anything in what you've provided would be giving you an infinite value.

Comment: new input system of fu@ckin unity return me Infinity... sorry i just tired

Comment: I don't know where you're setting your breakpoints or debug statements so I can't really help here.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Comment: I would expect the local functions to cause issues in general ... have you tried o move them out of `onFingerDown`?

Comment: which problems local fn can cause? i see only profits in local scope